# AVC Denied error creating DatagramSocket for Android Instant App

Tags: android, networking, udp, selinux, android-instant-apps

I have an Android app that uses UDP sockets for streaming data and it works well, but I can't get that part to work when run as an instant app.

As a simple example, I can create a DatagramSocket without error on an Android App (target SDK 29).

```
DatagramSocket datagramSocket = null;
try {
        datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        Log.i(TAG, "Created datagramSocket: "+datagramSocket);
} catch (SocketException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create datagram socket: "+e1);
        e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I see a positive confirmation that the socket was created:

```
Created datagramSocket: java.net.DatagramSocket@f0bee5c
```

If I rerun the same code as an Instant App then I get an error when creating the socket.

```
Failed to create datagram socket: java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err: java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.bind(IoBridge.java:108)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:104)
W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:112)
W/System.err:     at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:412)
W/System.err:     at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:262)
W/System.err:     at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:216)
....
type=1400 audit(0.0:106855): avc: denied { node_bind } for scontext=u:r:ephemeral_app:s0:c47,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:node:s0 tclass=udp_socket permissive=0 app=xxxx
....
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.bind(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.bind(ForwardingOs.java:74)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.bind(ForwardingOs.java:74)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.bind(IoBridge.java:104)
W/System.err:   ... 22 more
```

The app and the instant app both have the same permissions, including the INTERNET permission.
Requests on our HTTPS API server work fine for both the App and the Instant App.

The significant part seems to be the selinux error:

```
type=1400 audit(0.0:106855): avc: denied { node_bind } for scontext=u:r:ephemeral_app:s0:c47,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:node:s0 tclass=udp_socket permissive=0 app=xxxx
```

I think the avc line may be referencing https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/heads/master/prebuilts/api/29.0/public/net.te:

```
# Bind to ports.
allow {netdomain -ephemeral_app} node_type:{ icmp_socket rawip_socket tcp_socket udp_socket } node_bind;
allow {netdomain -ephemeral_app} port_type:udp_socket name_bind;
allow {netdomain -ephemeral_app} port_type:tcp_socket name_bind;
```

Can DatagramSockets be opened in instant apps?

We had a similar problem when supporting AppClips for iOS, and had to switch to using the Apple network framework. Is there a related fix for Android Instant Apps too?

Comment: You are right the avc denial corresponds to the selinux policy you mentioned, but that would mean it is not applied.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation EricLavault. I read the policy that for a non-ephemeral_app the name_bind would have been allowed.
Do you know if  "ephemeral_app" is a synonym for Instant App? I'm wondering whether there is some other configuration problem I have that is tripping my instant app to be mis-classified.

Comment: I'm not sure (not an android expert) but it's likely that instant and ephemeral have the same meaning here, as in general. The avc log shows the source and target security context, I think there is no misclassification and `ephemeral_app` is the appropriated scontext for an instant app. Then the modules  `ephemeral_app.te` and `net.te` should prevent the avc denials. Did you try to install these modules manually ?

Answer (score 1):

I posted a request to the Android issue tracker and got this response:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191070661

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
> Instant apps are required to protect all network traffic using encryption via something like TLS/HTTP: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9900182
>
> As a result instant apps are not allowed to directly bind sockets (TCP or UDP, enforced via selinux config) because an encryption cannot be verified/enforced. There is no solution at this time for utilizing UDP. A workaround would have to involve utilizing a connection based alternative (ie HTTPS).